# Oracle ADF: jbo:Commit does not work properly

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a jsp page using jbo tags and oracle adf to retrieve and update data from the database. (This the legacy code with java code inside jsp. There is no way to use el.)

```
<jbo:ApplicationModule id="AM_Payment" definition="testweb.AM_Payment" releasemode="Stateless" />
<jbo:ViewObject id="t1xvVO"  name="AM_Payment.T1XrefVView1"  />

<%
     t1xvVO.executeQuery();
     if (t1xvVO.hasNext()) {
         while (t1xvVO.hasNext()) {
             rowT1xv = t1xvVO.next();
             rowT1xv.setAttribute("T1xInvoiceT1150", t1_net_236);
         }      
     }
%>

<jbo:Commit appid="AM_Payment" />
```

The above code does not work. I got a test case with 14 records in the while loop. For each of them I set the attribute T1xInvoiceT1150. After the commit statement, the database is not updated. Anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The transaction cannot be committed because t1xvVO is the view object based on a view in database and it does not have an entity object.